# Just starting looking into python, Want to ask about beautiful soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I was trying to get the web crawling element in Google drive. What I want is the date the file was modified.

And I use F12 to find the elements, got the following selector

> body >
>   div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-AHmuwe-Hr88gd-OWB6Me.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-vyDMJf-aZ2wEe.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-i5oIFb.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-TSZdd
>
> > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-b0t70b.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-b0t70b-L6cTce > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-bN97Pc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-s2gQvd >
> >     div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-Tswv1b-nUpftc > div:nth-child(1) >
> >     div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-BKwaUc-bN97Pc > div > div:nth-child(6) >
> >     div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-BKwaUc-V67aGc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-Tswv1b-V67aGc

In order to do so I created following code using BS4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
req= requests.get ('https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_Lu1VHQI-yjvCPEwUhjonRyGHEczpRc/view')
base= req.text
print(base)
Find_ver=Sr.select('body > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-AHmuwe-Hr88gd-OWB6Me.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-vyDMJf-aZ2wEe.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-i5oIFb.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-TSZdd > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-b0t70b.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-b0t70b-L6cTce > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-bN97Pc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-s2gQvd > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-Tswv1b-nUpftc > div:nth-child(1) > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-BKwaUc-bN97Pc > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-BKwaUc-V67aGc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-Tswv1b-V67aGc' )
print (Find_ver)
```

But this keeps printing [] null dict, any help?

Edit: the link is shareable link. Does shareable link also requires Login?

Edit2: I solved it by  using selenium. Thx guys anyway!

Comment: google drive is hidden behind a login wall which bs4 won't be able to get through. You should look into google's drive api for accessing this information

Comment: @ Mikolaj Figurski  About the Api, I'm trying to make exe that every body can use, can drive api can make that kind of thing?  and the link above is Sharable link that everybody can access without the login, can this make any difference?

Comment: @Jun If you solved your issue, post an answer and click the checkmark to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using selenium. It showed the hidden feature which was not accessible through requesting html.

Thx guys for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems here:

a) You're not instantiating any soup instance

I'd actually recommend reading the docs here, since bs4 is described pretty well in a tutorial-like format: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.
Likely, you'll want to have something like this:

```
link = '<whatever website link>'
soup = bs(request.get(link))
```

b) The website you're retrieving likely doesn't have the information you want.

If you write the request text out to an html file, not really a visible date

[image]

c) `Sr` is undefined. Not sure what it's supposed to be

That said, the google drive api and the google python cli is the easiest way to do what you want to do. The cli (which is a python interface to the api itself) would absolutely be compile-able to an exe.